# Couchbase N1QL join query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

need help with a query in Couchbase enviroment.

Both document 1 and document 2 is in the same bucket.

First the query will get the document message1 using this query:

```
SELECT uid, message, sent_by FROM bucket USE KEYS "message1"
```

Second,  it need to get username from document 2. How can i create a join statement that will fetch username from a given document name, using the query above?

### Overview

**Document 1**
document name = message1

```
[
  {
    "uid": "1",
    "message": "hello",
    "sent_by": "username"
  }
]
```

**Document 2**
document name = user1

```
[
  {
    "username": "username"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the name of Document2 is based on the uid of Document1, that is, "user1" is based on uid=1, you can do the following:

```
SELECT d1.uid, d1.message, d1.sent_by, d2.username
FROM mybucket d1 USE KEYS "message1"
JOIN mybucket d2 ON KEYS "user" || d1.uid;
```

Comment: This query worked great. Great example that should be up on couchbase site

Comment: @geraldss Can you please explain how this query works? what is the `user` here ?

Comment: In this example, it's just data. Document 2's key is "user1". d1.uid == 1, so "user" || d1.uid == "user1".