# how to create index and use join in N1QL and Couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

I have three json like below in **same default Bucket**

**How Can I join this three json ??**

first

```
"Country|1":{
  "_id": 1,
  "_type": "Country",
  "currency": "Afghani",
  "iso2": "AF",
  "name": "Afghanistan"
}
```

second

```
"Company|a1091aa0-b548-11e6-957e-139be07f46df": 
  {
  "_id": "a1091aa0-b548-11e6-957e-139be07f46df",
  "_type": "Company",
  "companyTypes": [
    1
  ],
  "country": "Country|1",
}
```

Third

```
"Campaign|1001":{
  "_id": 1001,
  "_type": "Campaign",
  "banners": [],
  "carriers": [
    "Telstra"
  ],
  "country": 1,
  "created": "2016-03-08T18:30:00.000Z",

 }
```

here **key** is "name|_id" which i have wright before each json.

I have this type all json.
I have try to join query like below by reference of this source [Couchbase N1QL join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373860/couchbase-n1ql-join-query)

```
SELECT d1.*,d2.* FROM 
default d1 USE KEYS "Company|a1091aa0-b548-11e6-957e-139be07f46df"
JOIN default d2 ON KEYS d1.country;
```

I get the desire result.

But when I remove **USE KEYS "Company|a1091aa0-b548-11e6-957e-139be07f46df"** then run below query I get error for **INDEX**

```
SELECT d1.*,d2.*
FROM default d1 
JOIN default d2 ON KEYS d1.country;
```

Also I try to create index like below

```
CREATE INDEX campaign_user_co ON `default` (TOSTRING(country)) 
where _type="Company"
```

Even I am getting **Index** error.

No index available on keyspace default that matches your query.

Comment: What is the index error?

Comment: No index available on keyspace reachEffect that matches your query
I am getting this error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding a primary index.

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX ON default;
```

Substitute your keyspace name for **default**.

Comment: why I need Index ??

Comment: You need a primary index or a secondary index. Couchbase is a distributed database, so the data is not all in one place. The only way to query across the cluster is with an index.