# Couchbase - join using field without any relationship

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have two documents:

Document Id: A

```
{
  "name":"abc",
  "phone":"123"
}
```

and

Document Id: B

```
{
 "name":"abc",
 "state":"test-state"
}
```

Is it possible to join two documents using N1QL based on `name` field ? If yes, how can i achieve it?

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37373860/couchbase-n1ql-join-query), but is there a way to join documents without any relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Couchbase Joins are through document key relation.

Check this out https://dzone.com/articles/visually-explaining-n1ql-joins3

You can achieve this but not best approach

SELECT a, b FROM default a 
UNNEST (SELECT * FROM default WHERE b.state = "xyz") AS b 
WHERE a.name = b.name AND a.phone = "123"